# PHP loading / including files only if class is used

Tags: php

I have a couple of classes, and certain classes require only a part of an SDK.

For example

`class a {
    /* requires filea.php*/
}`

`class b { /*requires fileb.php*/ }`

Instead of including the files at the top like

```
require_once 'filea.php';
require_once 'fileb.php';

class a { /*do stuff*/ }
class b { /*do stuff*/ }
```

Can I just include them in the class, so one only loads when an object is made?

```
class a { require filea.php; /*do stuff*/ }
class b { require fileb.php; /*do stuff*/ }
```

Comment: Put one class per file, and include the class' dependencies at the top. When you need a class, you load it. If you don't need it, well don't load it.

Answer (score 1):

That involves [tight coupling which is considered a bad practice](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3armWGOtwA6nwJ%3amartinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/coupling.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESg-ohhDQzr3on1fPMUbbz3wArmjb3Z-pXLjIoUYCD3UuW2EoyVO71J066HW-rn_8z_o2snhrQe7tzIsSIttAjUQ2BaY7icOggyDh5utojhuItEtTup2lq06vzh8H4Vf1O-oRNga&sig=AHIEtbT4La65_UMC8rpSXg4ReQgifS_xqw&pli=1). You should be using [dependency injection](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=why%20coupling%20is%20bad#hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=s3x_T97JIpGE8QT2gYXOBw&ved=0CBwQvwUoAQ&q=php%20dependency%20injection&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=87c6230bd8e448f1&biw=1359&bih=864) if you need two classes to work together.

But, anyway, autoload should make this easier for you to do:

- [`__autoload()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php)
- [`SPL Autoload`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)

Comment: I really don't understand what tight coupling and dependency injection has to do with this question at all.

Comment: Class A now always requires filea.php. But what happens if they suddenly need to use a filea2.php some of the time? They now have to go back and edit the class and put and `if` statement in there to decide which to choose. The class shouldn't be doing that logic and is now less portable. With dependency injection the class just knows it is getting a class or file it needs without worrying about how that came about.

Comment: I am using this to make a wrapper for the PayPal SDK, where certain tasks only require a part of the SDK. It is safe to say that a class will only need the defined files. The autoload magic function seems to require me to define a class rather than a file, which I don't want to do.